# Application Loader is unable to upload your package

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, ipa, application-loader

I am uploading the .ipa file to iTunes and it is giving me the error *`We’re having trouble connecting to the App Store. Please try again later.`*

Can anyone guide me what is happening here as King Apple is not giving me any clue here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried uploading the ipa from Xcode itself?

Comment: If you are using the old version of Application Loader then update and check in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried a couple of things but nothing seems to be working. What worked for me was kill Xcode, kill application loader and mac restart. It will work. Yes, don't look at me like this, Thanks to Apple.